# RxBinding and DataBinding which is the best choice for MVVM

Tags: mvvm, rx-java, viewmodel, android-databinding, rx-binding

Recently , I was confusing about Rxbinding and Databinding for my project.
Basically , my project is applying MVVM architecture.
However there was some screen is created with Databinding and other one is worked with RxBinding.

I am considering to do refactor code and apply all with Databinding. 
In fact, in some case Rxbinding is a best way to implement (Of course databinding also can use for this case) so I do not want to change.
To be honest, there was some usecase that is very difficult to implement by Databinding concept.

My question:
Base on the concept of MVVM architecture, View should not has data or logic and just observe data from ViewModel to update immediately its changes.

So, what is the essential difference between Rxbinding and Databinding ?
When should I use Rxbinding and when Databinding?